# Can ItemReaders just pass in the record read and not need a lineMapper t o convert to an object

Tags: spring-batch

I'm asking if I can pass into the ItemProcessors the entire delimited record read in the ItemReader as one long string.

I have situations with unpredictable data.  The file is pipe-delimited, but even with that, a single double-quote will have a parse error using Spring Batch's ItemReader.

In a standalone java application I wrote code using Spring's StringUtils class.  I read in the full delimited record as a String (BufferedReader), then call Spring's StringUtils.delimitedListToStringArray(...,...).  This gets all the characters whether valid or not, and then I can do a search/replace to get things like any single double-quote or commas in the fields.

My standalone Java program is a down-n-dirty solution.  I'm turning it into a Spring Batch job for the long term solution.  It's a monthly process, and it's an impractical, if not impossible, task to get SAP users to keep trash out of data fields (i.e. fat-finger city).

I see where it appears I have to have a domain object for the input record to be mapped into.  Is this correct, or can i do a pass-through scenario, and let me handle the parsing myself using StringUtils?

The pipe-delimited records turn into comma-delimited records. There's really no need to create a domain object and do all the field set mapping.

Am happy for ideas if I'm approaching this the wrong way.

Thank you in advance.

Thanks,
Michael

EDIT:

```
This is the error, and the record.  The lone double-quote in column 6 is the problem.  I can't control the input, so I'm scrubbing each field (all Strings) for unwanted characters.  So, my solution was to skip the line mapping and use StringUtils to do it myself--as I've done as mentioned earlier.

Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 33526 in resource=[URL [file:/temp/comptroller/myfile.txt]], input=[xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx x xxx xxxxxxx xxxx xxxx "x|xxx|xxx|xxxxx|xx|xxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxx|xxx|xx |xxx ]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:182)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:85)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:90)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:87)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectTokenCountException: Incorrect number of tokens found in record: expected 15 actual 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the domain objects you read from `ItemReader`s, write to `ItemWriter`s, and optionally process with `ItemProcessor`s can be any `Object`, they can be `String`s.

So the short answer is yes, you should be able to use a `FlatFileItemReader` to read one line at a time, pass it to `SomeItemProcessor<String,String>`, which replaces your pipes with commas (and handles existing commas) with whatever code you want, and sends those converted lines to a `FlatFileItemWriter`. Spring Batch includes common implementations of the `LineTokenizer` and `LineAggregator` classes which could help.

In this scenario, Spring Batch would be acting like a glorified search replace tool, with saner failure handling. To answer the bigger question of whether you should be using domain objects, or at least beans, think about whether you want to perform other tasks in the conversion process, like validation.

P.S. I'm not aware that FFItemReader blows up on a single double-quote, might want to file that as a bug.

Comment: I added the error.  I will look into the Spring provided implementations on the LineMapper.  I started that route but wasn't immediately successful.  This exercise is a prototype of sorts--my first Spring Batch project.  I even tried to write a common generic method where, in the item processor, I could pass in the bean, and with reflection, scrub every String field for quotes, commas, and double-quotes.  Boy, that was dreadfully slow.  So, I'm backing up to maybe just taking the file record and scrubbing array columns in a loop before sending it to the ItemWriter.

Comment: PassThroughLineMapper is the answer I'm looking for, in this case.  Thanks, @Emerson.

Comment: I skimmed through the Spring Batch code and saw that " is used as an escape character in the DelimitedLineTokenizer. It basically allows the delimiter to appear in a field, which is most probably the cause of the incorrect token count and the exception. Try calling setQuoteCharacter and setting the quote character to something else.